# Creating Replica using ArcPY with check_out type

Tags: arcpy, personal-geodatabase, replication

I am running the following command in python and it works fine no error but it does not generate a mdb in output path folder and give me the input path result as output child source

```
arcpy.CreateReplica_management("AHSAN.Point_1120","CHECK_OUT",
r"D:\Ahsan\January-16\Zaeem         \mdb_generation","CheckOut_Output_3","FULL","CHILD_DATA_SENDER","USE_DEFAULTS","DO_NOT_REUSE","DO_NOT_GET_RELATED","AHSAN.Point_1120","ARCHIVING")

<Result 'D:\\Ahsan\\January-16\\Zaeem\\mdb_generation'>
```

I need to create mdb in output path folder. I have tried the same thing with model builder but no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The target geodatabase needs to exist for the `arcpy.CreateReplica_management()` to work; this tool will not create it for you.

From [Create Replica - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-replica.htm):

> The local geodatabase or geodata service that will host the child
>   replica. Geodata services are used to represent remote geodatabases.
>   The geodatabase can be an ArcSDE, file, or personal geodatabase. For
>   two-way replicas the child geodatabase must be ArcSDE. For one-way and
>   check-out replicas the geodatabase can be personal, file, or ArcSDE.
>   **Personal or file geodatabases must already exist before running this
>   tool.**

Create your check-out geodatabase in the target location and point the tool at this geodatabase.  You could use `arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path, out_name)` in your script to create it for you.  See [Create File GDB - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-file-gdb.htm).

**EDIT:**
If you need a Personal Geodatabase MDB try creating that instead using `arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(out_folder_path, out_name)`.  See [Create Personal GDB - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-personal-gdb.htm)

**EDIT 2:**
The following arcpy script will create an MDB personal geodatabase file, and create a check-out replica using that MDB and the specified feature classes.

```
import arcpy

checkOutPath = "D:\\Ahsan\\January-16\\Zaeem\\mdb_generation" # Path to your new MDB
checkOutMDB = "CheckOutMDB" # Name of your new MDB
checkOut = "{}\\{}.mdb".format(checkOutPath, checkOutMDB) # Path to your Replica MDB
replicaName = "MyCheckOutReplica" # Name of your replica

# Your Feature Classes to Replicate go here, separated by Semicolon ;
# Please note I have added a "Point_1121" for example
inputs = " 'Database Connections\\GeoDB.sde\\GeoDB.AHSAN.Point_1120' ; 'Database Connections\\GeoDB.sde\\GeoDB.AHSAN.Point_1121' " 

print "Create PGDB"
arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(checkOutPath, checkOutMDB, "CURRENT") # Creates new MDB File (using name in CheckOutMDB) in the specified path (using CheckOutPath)

print "CreateReplica"
# Creates Check Out Replica in new MDB (from CheckOut) replicating feature classes listed in Inputs, with the name in ReplicaName
arcpy.CreateReplica_management(inputs, "CHECK_OUT", checkOut, replicaName, "FULL", "CHILD_DATA_SENDER", "USE_DEFAULTS", "DO_NOT_REUSE", "DO_NOT_GET_RELATED", "", "ARCHIVING")
```

Comment: I create a gdb file in my local directory and specified the path like this...

arcpy.CreateReplica_management("AHSAN.Point_1120","CHECK_OUT",r"D:\Ahsan\January-16\Zaeem\mdb_generation\mdb_path\myfile.gdb","CheckOut_Output_3","FULL","CHILD_DATA_SENDER","USE_DEFAULTS","DO_NOT_REUSE","DO_NOT_GET_RELATED","AHSAN.Point_1120","ARCHIVING")

<Result 'D:\\Ahsan\\January-16\\Zaeem\\mdb_generation\\mdb_path\\myfile.gdb'>

But replica still not generated...

Comment: I need to have a mdb as output.

Comment: I have edited my answer for MDB (Personal Geodatabase)

Comment: how i will specify that mdb file as output.

Comment: I have modified your arcpy script to create Personal Geodatabase MDB and then create a Check Out replica using that MDB as child geodatabase.  Please remember to change/correct filepaths to match your requirements.